# Python Esri ArcPy functions do not work properly in command prompt but it works properly in PyScripter IDE

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, installation, python-2.7, anaconda

I have a simple Python script that imports the `arcpy` module. It works quite perfect in ArcMap's Python Window and PyScripter IDE but in the Command Prompt console some functions like `arcpy.listdatasets()` or `arcpy.Describe(workspace).connectionProperties` return empty: `[]` and causes error. Even the  `arcpy.ListTables()` brings tables outside featureDatasets but not the inside ones!! so workspace is ok as well.

I put the Script in C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4 that contains ArcGIS python.exe and run CMD as Admin and run by command :

C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4>python Script1.py

Some part of Script run, some don't.

the command Line error:

[image]

The PyScripter result that is ok :

[image]

environment variable added like  :

[image]

1. Python version is 2.7 and ArcGIS is 10.4.1,
2. I added this path to Global environment variable as Esri Said:
   C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4 But the issue is the Script is in Python.exe folder and this Directory contains All Lib and DLLs folder.
3. I've tried Anaconda command line.
4. No permission problem, user is admin and access everything.
5. Tried `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")` and did not work.
6. Tried in Windows Server 2012-R2 & 2016.
7. I've tried different kind of SDE Connection with either SA user and Windows Authentication. both result the same and did not work.

Since I'm going to schedule this task need to work in Command Prompt.

What is wrong?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.4 is no longer supported, but it still works if you set it up correctly. Unfortunately, you've left out the necessary details of how you set it up.  Of particular interest are what you've added to the PATH in the cmd.exe script, the working directory of the Command Prompt, and the exact commands you've issued. Anaconda and the 2.7 ArcPy environment aren't exactly friends, so that may be your problem.

Comment: What environment variable values do you have configured?  What' command line command are you running?  What's the script content (or a cut-down simplified version of it that still fails)?  We need a LOT more information that you've provided.  Update your original question with all these details.

Comment: Thank you for your mention, I updated the question and added the items.

Comment: Likely related to your SDE connection file because that is the part of the code that behaves differently when running as administrator.  Does your SDE connection file use OS Authentication by chance?

Comment: I have tried both kind of authentication, with sa user and window authentication

Comment: You need to put the connection file in the script framework to run it in batch. It's a violation of best security practice to use `sa` in a connection file for anything but geodatabase upgrade.

Comment: problem was solved : it was quite simple, there is 2 folder in C:\Python27  1-ArcGIS10.4 and 2-ArcGISx6410.4  the command prompt should run in 64bit mode in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe inside second folder ArcGISx6410.4 solved my problem after 3 days of struggling